# Undo ability not working after adding Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script to hide or show Rows with a specific value, it is working well, only I have problem that if I do change the value of any cell in the Spreadsheet even in other sheet like (sheet2) and I want to Undo that change, the Undo ability not working till I repeat it more than 30 times!!! And If I delete the script, it works normally.

Do I have to add, change or delete any code of this script to make Undo Ability working normally as before adding script?

Thank you

I tried to changed this line: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`
to let Undo working normally
or to make it atleast be affecting in specific sheet but I could't.

Here is the full script...

```js
function myShowHide() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (i = 4; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var status = sheet.getRange("J" + i).getValues();

    if (status == "X") {
      sheet.showRows(i);
    }
  }

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (i = 4; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var status = sheet.getRange("J" + i).getValues();

    if (status != "X") {
      sheet.hideRows(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your script linked to an onEdit trigger?

Comment: Display the last Row with logger.Log(lastRow); it is possible that because of previous actions your last row is a (now) empty row with a high index, which makes your for loop perform additional steps to hide the all the empty rows. If this is not the source of your problem - I would need to have a look at your spreadsheet to see where the problem comes from.

Comment: Yes, it is linked to an onEdit trigger (From spreadsheet - On open)

Comment: There is no problem to have a look at my spreadsheet, I'll make share for you. Thanks alot.

Comment: Please embed the link the spreadsheet in your question - make sure not to include any sensitive private information

Comment: Here is the link:
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19hucbB0WAZlI0ZDz8Js95ugb7yjv5MugQyBaIP7TFmw/)
Thanks

Comment: You need to give permission to open it

Comment: Before I gave permission to your ID, now I gave premission to anyone

Comment: Your code as it is now loops on every cell edit through 375 rows and either shows or hides each one of them separately. This means that to undo the action that fired the OnEdit triger, first you need to undo the 375 actions performed by the script after this. This is why I suggest you to run your show-hide script manually when you need it, rather than automatically on every cell edit. You can e.g. implement a button in your sheet that allows you to run the script when you click on it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDMY9o23uBM

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running this with an installable onEdit() trigger then this will solve the problem of interacting with other sheets.

```
function myShowHide(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(4,10,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var sA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
    if(sA[i][0]=="X") {
      sh.showRows(i+4);
    }else{
      sh.hideRows(i+4);
    }
  }
}
```

I setup an installable onEdit trigger for this function.

```
function myNewShowHide(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  myShowHide(e);
}
```

But solving the problem on Sheet1 depends upon how you want the sheet to run.  If you run it with an edit trigger then anytime your editing anywhere on the sheet it runs.  You could limit the edit range but that requires knowing what you want to do with the sheet and I don't know that.

> My recommendation is not to run this kind of function with an onEdit() trigger.  This one will run much faster because I get all of the data at one time but the rows are still shown or hidden one at a time.

Comment: Thanks friend for your response, but unfortunately it is not working, when I added these two lines the main function was not working, that means it did not hide or show rows, I feel that there is something wrong in my side, but I don't know where!!

Comment: I changed it a little try it again.  Just copy, paste and edit to test.  Don't run from script editor because it needs the event object which is gets from the edit trigger.  Keep you old function because it's part of the new one.

Comment: After last change the main function is working well, but still the Undo ability not working!! May you kindly type the full script for me together the old and new one, to be sure that I put it correctly. Thanks alot.